# PHP - Incrementing Variables Efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Im using functions for logging in a user, When they login but fail either by no captcha sent, failed captcha or failed login it will give there IP a `Try`. When they reach 5 tries they get blocked from the login page for approximately 1 hour. I have a function that updates the MySQL Column to increment there try count and last try date. But from looking at PHP's documents it states:

> Note: The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and
>   strings. Arrays, objects and resources are not affected.

My function gets the try count from the Database and then tries updating it. My SQL result for fetching the Try count is by default an Array because of how PDO works. So how can I efficiently increment an array?

I was thinking of doing a foreach condition and use the `.=`opperator to save it to a string and from there increment. But is that really the most efficient way?

Thank you.

P.S: I'm not showing any example code e.t.c because this question is simple enough. I have searched around on here and couldn't find a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment it in an update query directly. When you want to add a try, simply:

```
UPDATE `tries` SET `tries` = `tries` + 1 WHERE `ip` = '127.0.0.1';
```

Just replace the IP with the actual IP.

Comment: My Query is: `query("UPDATE tries SET tries = :tries, ipbanned = :ipbanned, last_try = :last_try WHERE ip = :ip",array(":tries"=>$tries,":ipbanned"=>$ipbanned,":last_try"=>$date,":ip"=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))` May I ask what the difference is?

Comment: The difference is that you don't need to supply `:tries` as query parameter. MySQL supports incrementing an integer field by just using `+1` on the field. That way, PHP doesn't have to do the incrementing for you.

Answer (score 2):

To understand why your question is wrong, you have to understand what an array is.

An array is just a "bag" that holds other variables. so, your question sounds like "How can I pay for a two beers with my pocket?". The thing is, you can't pay with a pocket. you have to take the cash out of the pocket and then use that cash.

Exactly the same thing goes with arrays: you have to extract the returned data from array, and then you are free to perform any operation on its contents. On the contents, remember, not on the bag.

But for the efficient solution, go for the other answer, which solved your initial problem the right way - without the need of selecting any arrays at all.

And just a side note

> MySQL result for fetching the Try count is by default an Array because of how PDO works.

As a matter of fact, PDO can work in many different ways. For example, it can return scalar values all right.

Comment: I understand, Thank you. :)

Comment: I like your comparison on arrays and beer +1 for education with a twist :)

Comment: Towards your side note, I was just implying the default output on how PDO works, You can get it to output differently of course but I was implying on the default most used ways :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add..

IMO you should be using a separate table for incorrect login attempts.  There are many reasons for this, but one of the important is that any attack is likely to rotate usernames and not only passwords in the attempt.

Having a separate table that records all incorrect logins allows you to much more easily query for an amount of incorrect logins in xx time.  Incorrect logins attached to a user limits your ability to detect DoS and brute force attacks coming from scripted sources as you can only look at the username attempted if it actually existed in the first place.

However, you can relate a field in the table to the users ID, so that you can track users independently, then on successful login, the records that relate to that user could be deleted.

To give you a working example.  I have built in the following functionality into the commercial Symfony project that I work on on a daily basis.

**table example**

```
userID    --- foreign key (not mandatory)
IP        --- mandatory
timestamp --- mandatory
```

we query the data like this:

- Overall failed attempts for a particular subdomain (we have lots of them in use using the same system)

  - the system is used in schools, so we have to cater for naughty students!
- Overall failed attempts in the last minute

  - system sleeps for a random time based on a base value x the amount. (a bit of a hacky way to try to trip up script attacks)
- Overall attempts for a particular user

  - similar to your example.. compares to preconfigured amounts then warns/disables users accordingly.  If it blocks sends an email to the helpdesk team.

this is by no means a suggested list, or an example of what **should** be done.. its merely what we decided on our applications circumstances.

The point is, without a separate table much of this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Lol, Read line 1 and boom. Stopped reading xD It is already in a seperate table. If you read my query on the selected answer you can see it says `UPDATE tries<-- SET`... tries is my seperate column.

Comment: then you should have put that in your question.  There was nothing in your question that mentioned a separate table was being used, hence I felt it important to point out to readers of the post that it should be considered.  People dont always read comments.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't think I needed to :/